# Summarize items in numpy ndarray based on repetitive "blocks" of different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, summarize

I have a large matrix and want to summarize (e.g. calculate mean) values in selected rows according to differently sized blocks of repetitive elements in another row. Maybe numpy offers an efficient way for this, so I do not have to iterate over all values in the long axis.

Additionally, I would like to calculate the N (excluding potential nan) of values used for each mean value, and also keep the first value of the row containing non numeric data.

As an example of what I have and what I want to calculate:

```
values1 = np.random.rand(20)
values2 = np.random.rand(20)
values_str = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a','a', 'b', 'b','b','b', 'a','a','a', 'b','b','b','b', 'a','a', 'b','b' ])
blocks = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1]) #makes 7 blocks of values

mymatrix = np.vstack((values1, values2, blocks, values_str))  
mymatrix = mymatrix.astype(object) #my real matrix was derived from a pandas df, seems this is why it was of type object
```

in this case I want to output a "summary matrix" with 7 elements per row, looking something like this:

```
summarymatrix = [[ 'mean from values1[0, 1, 2], mean from values1[3, 4],  ... '], 
                   [ 'mean from values2[0, 1, 2], mean from values2[3, 4],  ... '],
                   [  'a', 'a', ...],  #keep first item from each block
                   [  3, 2, ... ]]     #N values used for calculation of mean (excluding nan)
```

My current approach is that, using np.diff(). Am I going in the right direction? Also concerning speed?

```
#this works if block values are numeric, but they can easily be converted 
locchange = np.diff(mymatrix[3].astype(int)) # use diff to find boarders between "blocks"
blockborders = np.where(locchange != 0)[0]
blockborders = np.append(blockborders, blocksforsum.size-1) #add the last element

start = 0
for i in blockborders:
    
    summary1 = np.nanmean(values1[start : i+1])
    summary2 = np.nanmean(values1[start : i+1])
    selected_nosum = np.array(values_nosum[start])
    N_sum1 = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(values1[start : i+1]))
    N_sum2 = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(values2[start : i+1]))
    
    print (start, i, summary1, summary2, selected_nosum, N_sum1, N_sum2)
    
    start = i+1
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from some correction concerning how to create *mymatrix*.

Note that *values1* and  *values2* are of *float* type,
whereas *values_str* is of *<U1* (1 character *string*) type.

So if you attempt to create *mymatrix* your way (using *np.vstack*) then
all elements are actually of *string* type, what would hamper computation
of mean values for defined slices of 2 first rows.

To avoid it and have each element of its proper type, create *mymatrix* as
an empty array of *object* type and then save each "composite" array
in its respective row:

```
mymatrix = np.empty((3, values1.size), dtype='object')
mymatrix[0] = values1
mymatrix[1] = values2
mymatrix[2] = values_str
```

(no need to include *blocks* there).

Then, to create a list of **columnar slices** from *blocks*, run:

```
import itertools
i = 0
slc = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(blocks):
    j = i + len(list(g))
    slc.append(slice(i, j))
    i = j
```

(print *slc* to see the result).

To get the first valid (not null) value from an array, to be used for
*values_str*, define the following function:

```
def getFirstValid(arr):
    return arr[np.nonzero(arr)][0]
```

To get first 2 rows of your expected output you could run:

```
np.vstack([ mymatrix[:2, sl].mean(axis=1) for sl in slc ]).T
```

To get the third row, you could use the just function defined and run:

```
[ getFirstValid(mymatrix[2, sl]) for sl in slc ]
```

It is not clear from which row of *mymatrix* to compute the number of
non-null values (the 4th row of your expected result).
If from the third row (*values_str*), you could run:

```
[ np.nonzero(mymatrix[2, sl])[0].size for sl in slc ]
```

But you can get the **whole** expected result stacking vertically all
the above partial results:

```
result = np.vstack([np.vstack([ mymatrix[:2, sl].mean(axis=1) for sl in slc ]).T,
    [ getFirstValid(mymatrix[2, sl]) for sl in slc ],
    [ np.nonzero(mymatrix[2, sl])[0].size for sl in slc ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this started as a pandas dataframe - I would do all of this using pandas, it is performant and the api is suited to your task:

```
# setup:
# import pandas as pd
# convert back to dataframe
# df = pd.DataFrame(mymatrix.T, columns=["values1", "values2", "blocks", "value_str"])
# df[["values1","values2"]] = df[["values1","values2"]].astype(float)

# data operations
df["group_num"] = np.cumsum(df.blocks != df.blocks.shift())
df_summary = df.groupby(group_num)[["values1", "values2"]].mean().rename(columns={"values1": "values1_mean", "values2": "values2_mean"})
df_summary["first_val"] = df.groupby(group_num).value_str.first()
df_summary["n_values"] = df.groupby(group_num).values1.count()
```

Output:

```
        values1_mean  values2_mean first_val  n_count
blocks
1           0.409260      0.373049         a        3
2           0.683461      0.873512         a        2
3           0.517973      0.463824         b        4
4           0.640845      0.735928         a        3
5           0.381600      0.213839         b        3
6           0.619728      0.091368         b        2
7           0.413441      0.344485         a        3
```

In requested form:

```
array([[0.4092604066125924, 0.6834609605376954, 0.5179732143191805,
        0.6408445371272942, 0.3816002299674925, 0.6197275933765357,
        0.4134405399424737],
       [0.3730486823681607, 0.873512199828059, 0.4638244098291482,
        0.7359275944860505, 0.21383937735995917, 0.09136840552312986,
        0.34448514831094634],
       ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'],
       [3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
```